# How can I aggregate over the _score

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregate

I tried to run an aggregate query over the _score field on Elastic Search with no results. Seems it is not possible to use the _score field, maybe because it is not a field of the document. How can I aggregate over the _score ?

This is my query:

```
{
  "_source": false, "explain": false, "from": 0, "size": 0,
  "aggs" : {
    "score_ranges" : {
       "range" : {
          "field" : "_score",
          "ranges" : [
            { "to"   : 50 },
            { "from" : 50, "to" : 75 },
            { "from" : 75 }
          ]
        }
      }
  },
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": { }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  "aggs": {
    "scores_histogram": {
      "histogram": {
        "script": "return _score.doubleValue() * 10",
        "interval": 3
      }
    }
  }
```

or, with `ranges`:

```
  "aggs": {
    "score_ranges": {
      "range": {
        "script": "_score",
        "ranges": [
          {
            "to": 50
          },
          {
            "from": 50,
            "to": 75
          },
          {
            "from": 75
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

And you need to enable dynamic scripting.